# SQL not returning a value if no row exist for time queried

Tags: sql, datetime, count, mariadb, recursive-query

I'm writing this SQL query which returns the number of records created in an hour in last 24 hours. I'm getting the result for only those hours that have a non zero value. If no records were created, it doesn't return anything at all.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT HOUR(timeStamp) as hour, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM `events` 
WHERE timeStamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY HOUR(timeStamp)
ORDER BY HOUR(timeStamp)
```

The output of current Query:

```
+-----------------+----------+
| hour            | count    |
+-----------------+----------+
|              14 |        6 |
|              15 |        5 |
+-----------------+----------+
```

But i'm expecting 0 for hours in which no records were created. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you share your input and expected output ?

Comment: In which DB you are looking for?

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server

Comment: @SurajKumar . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: @SurajKumar Maria db is the actual flavor of sql I'm using

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272957/mysql-query-for-obtaining-count-per-hour

Comment: Do you understand that you have partial first and last hours?  And there will be one output row, with the data for those two partial hours added together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to generate a table of numbers from 0 to 23 and left join it with your original table.

Here is a query that uses a recursive query to generate the list of hours (if you are running MySQL, this requires version 8.0):

```
with hours as (
    select 0 hr
    union all select hr + 1 where h < 23
)
select h.hr, count(e.eventID) as cnt
from hours h
left join events e 
    on e.timestamp > now() - interval 1 day
    and hour(e.timestamp) = h.hr
group by h.hr
```

If your RDBMS does not support recursive CTEs, then one option is to use an explicit derived table:

```
select h.hr, count(e.eventID) as cnt
from (
    select 0 hr union all select 1 union all select 2 ... union all select 23
) h
left join events e 
    on e.timestamp > now() - interval 1 day
        and hour(e.timestamp) = h.hr
group by h.hr
```

Comment: You might also want to consider creating a number table for generating your superset table (all of the hours, in your case).

There are lots of examples of how to create a number table so I won't expand on that but after you have one just use it as the base of your query and then left join your data, filtering the number table on BETWEEN 1 and 23 (or whatever your DB allows) btw: did you know that you tagged MSSql as well as MySql in your question. Which are you using?)

Comment: It's MySQL @DavidBridge

Comment: Cool. Thanks for updating your question tags. The suggestion on a number table is generic to any DB so may help you. The reply by GMB is similar to generating a number table on the fly so should work perfectly for you.

Comment: @DavidBridge I'm supposed to create a table named "h" and with the column "hr" containing the numbers as rows right?

Comment: Yes. Although when I do it, I just make a standard table and called Number with a single column called n and I put the values 0 to 1 million in it. I do this because number tables are useful for lots of things (but especially the scenario you are using it for) and so I don't want the table to be specific to one problem. I use MS SQL so I cannot tell you how to make it in MySql but basically just create any query that joins a huge amount of rows then generate a rowid for each row and insert it into a new table called numbers. Someone here who knows MySQL will have script for you.

Comment: @GMB It's not clear what's the name of the table and field in number table. Can you brief it?

Comment: @ShrihariPrakash: the name of your table is `mytable`. The hours table is aliased `hours` and/or `h` in the queries.